# Modifing and uploading Tridion Building Blocks gives error when previewing and publishing

Tags: 2011, publishing

We have an issue when we modify and upload our Tridion Building Blocks.

When using the template builder everything is working correctly but when using preview or doing a publish we get an error message.

For preview, the message is: object not set to an instance of an object?

For publish, we see the message "The number of render failures has exceeded its specified failure limit of 0" and  "There was an error generating the xml document"

The workaround we have now is to restart all the services, com objects and app pools on the cms server.  After that preview and publishing are working again.

Tridion version is 2011 without service packs.

Has someone seen a similar behavior and what was the definitive solution so we don't have to restart every time?

Comment: I don't remember having that issue. I would certainly consider applying - at least - 2011 SP1...

Comment: Needing to restart COM+ and associated processes is usually indicative of a memory issue. How much physical memory does the server have? Are you publishing individual pages or whole structure groups after updating your TBBs? The error messages you specify are quite generic, can you provide any additional log information from the server or some form of stack trace?

Comment: We are working on a plan to upgrade to SP1 for this project but this takes some time.  I hoped that their was a faster solution in the meantime

Comment: We have the issue already when publishing only one page and also when using the preview in Tridion.  The log file don't tell more then the error messages.  I will try to place some stack trace info when we have the issue again.

Answer (score 5):

We had received the similar error when we had installed the SDL Tridion 2011.

As per the recommendation, we then applied the Hot Fix roll up for SDL Tridion 2011 and the issue got resolved.

Did you apply the HR# 1 for SDL Tridion 2011, if not (or unsure about it), then I would recommend applying it and then retry.

Comment: Thanks for the info Pankaj Gaur.  HR# 1 is not installed.  We will go directly for SP1 and hot fox roll up for SP1.  Unfortunately this will not before June so we will continue to do the restarts.  I will do a follow up when the SP is installed.

Comment: As an alternate approach, you may want to raise this with Tridion Support and they may provide you a patch if possible

Comment: I tend to agree with @PankajGaur you should talk with SDL support to see if they have a patch independent of HR1 which may resolve the issue for you.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you have some code that runs only when the render mode is Preview / PreviewDynamic? - Code that runs only when the page is in preview mode.

Certainly worth having a search through your solution to see if that's the case.